# Continuous Delivery issues with S3 and AWS CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, latency, continuous-delivery

I'm building out a series of content websites, and I've built a working CodePipeline that allows me to push edits to HTML files on github that instantly reflect in the S3 bucket, and consequently on the live website.

I created a cloudfront distro to get HTTPS for my website. The certificate and distro work fine, and it populates with my index.html in my S3 bucket, but **the changes made via my github pipeline to the S3 bucket are reflected in the S3 bucket but not the CloudFront Distribution**.

From what I've read, the edge locations used in cloudfront don't update their caches super often, and when they do, they might not update the *edited* index.html file because it has the same name as the old version.

I don't want to manually rename my index.html file in S3 every time one of my writers needs to post a top 10 Tractor Brands article or implement an experimental, low-effort clickbait idea, so that's pretty much off the table.

My overall objective is to build something where teams can quickly add an article with a few images to the website that goes live in minutes, and I've been able to do it so far but not with HTTPS.

If any of you know a good way of instantly updating CloudFront Distributions without changing file names, that would be great. Othterwise I'll probably have to start over because I need my sites secured and the ability to update them instantly.

You people are awesome. Thanks a million for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [invalidate files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html) from the edge caches. It's a simple and quick process.

You can automate the process yourself in your pipeline, or you could potentially use a third-party tool such as [aws-cloudfront-auto-invalidator](https://github.com/rewindio/aws-cloudfront-auto-invalidator).